# Regular Expression to reject any string that do not contain any of these characters?

Tags: python, regex

I want to create a python function that takes a word as argument and uses regular expression package `re` to reject words that contain any character other than '0123456789:MF' and '\s'.

Structure:

```
def function(word):
    pattern = re.compile('REGEXHERE')
    if pattern.match(word):
         return True
    else:
         return False
```

The problem is that I do not know the regular expression that does just that.

**SOLUTION**

Since I can't answer my own question yet, I publish here the solution provided by @MartinBonner that worked just fine:

```
def function(word):
    return not re.compile('[^0-9::MF\\s]').search(word)
```

Comment: the missing regex is the problem i think

Comment: `if condition : return True else return False` is better written as `return condition`.

Comment: do you mean with `\s` the regex `\s`?

Comment: he meant `return pattern.match(word)`. You don't need the if statement

Comment: I would 1.  Invert the characters being searched for.  2.  Invert the test (return true if they are found), 3.  Use `search`, not `match`.  As a one-liner:  `def function(word): return ! re.compile('[^0-9::MF\\s]').search(word)`

Comment: Thank you @MartinBonner, your solution worked perfectly! Just changed: `def function(word): return not re.compile('[^0-9::MF\\s]').search(word)`

Comment: @pmanresa93 be aware that this will match the empty string

Comment: You should always be able to post answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a character class. Your regex should be:

```
'[\\d:MF\\s]+'
```

To ensure the whole string is matched, you surround it with `^` and `$`:

```
'^[\\d:MF\\s]+$'
```

Comment: That's an inefficient way to do it : rather than matching the whole string to make sure all its characters are accepted, you'd better match up to the first character that isn't accepted

Comment: @Aaron Doesn't this accomplish that? The match should fail in `O(n)` time.

Comment: Hmmm so my justification was stupid, you're right that both will fail/succeed as quickly. I think my option is marginally better memory-wise because it only has to match a single character, while your option will have to maintain the matched-so-far string in memory

Comment: I've been running some tests on regex101 ([with yours](https://regex101.com/r/z7UhSW/1) / [with mine](https://regex101.com/r/jPK06b/1)), it looks like my option performs generally better with their PCRE engine. It also points out that they don't behave the same way with the empty string, since your regex guarantees at least one correct character while mine just guarantees at most 0 incorrect character.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `\s` from the regex reserved words, take this

```
^[\d:MF\s]+$
```